# Excessive memory reserved for caching on Linux

Tags: linux, caching

How can I find out that it is causing excessive reserved of memory caching?

[image: About of 10gb is reserved by caches]

I only free space with:

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

About of 10gb is reserved by caches. See list proccess before of run drop_caches:

[image: Process List]

Software version:

```
mysqld: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Linux: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS -> 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ClamAV: 0.98.7/23224/Tue Mar 21 08:29:04 2017
Apache: 2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server built: Sep 23 2015 15:34:04
```

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for this site, but what is it that you perceive as a problem? Caching is _good_. Memory that would otherwise be unused is used as cache, and when that memory is needed for processes, the cached data will be dropped.

Comment: Also, see this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. The OS can be used it Memory in other programs. I do not dominate this subject and for this I ask. Thanks a lot for the link.